# Content coming from a web application sometimes randomly shuffled

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, random-effects

We develop a Java web application which is run on Tomcat. It's been installed on many computers and it's working without problems. Recently, on a single remote installation, it exhibits very strange behavior: Sometimes content coming through HTTP to the browser is randomly shuffled - wrong data being served for a given URL. Most often it manifests as images being randomly exchanged on a web page. But it's not limited to images, it happened to me that instead of a HTML page the browser got one of the images instead.

I tried to debug the problem using FireBug + [NetExport](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/netexport/), and so far I gathered:

- It appears randomly. Most of the time content is error-free, the problem occurs only from time to time.
- The same application runs on many installations, but only this single installation produces the error.
- It's not connected to a particular browser - we tried different browsers from different computers and the problem persists.
- It occurs when viewed from the server itself (localhost) too, which rules out some broken transparent proxy on the way.
- Both images and HTML pages are affected.
- If wrong content is received, the data itself is consistent: `Content-Length`, `Content-Type`, `ETags`, etc. - everything matches the content. Just that it's wrong data for a given URL.

I'm truly puzzled, I've never seen such an error. I'd be grateful for any ideas how to investigate the problem further.

Comment: Does your web app do any internal forwarding? Could that be broken?

Comment: @JimGarrison No, we don't use forwarding. And it even occurs with static images stored in files that are being directly served by Tomcat.

Comment: What do your tomcat logs show? Does the request look right?

Comment: @JimGarrison I have some problems enabling the access logs, for some reasons they're empty (maybe some buffering problem on Windows). When I solve this, I'll post an update.